# The color (or contrast) of visited links is too light to be readable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This has been fixed and will be live after next build on production.

---

After visiting a link, one can't clearly distinguish between this link and surrounding text.

[image]

[image]